# Returning all possible values instead of a VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

So I've looked up tutorials on how to do this, and I'm still struggling, so I could use some expert help. I know it involves a very complex nested formula with things like `SMALL`, `ROW`, `INDEX`, etc...

So here are two screenshots that provide a sample of what I'm looking for. In realities there is over 1000 rows, but this makes it easier for you guys.

So here is my first example, lets call this Sheet1!:

[image]

Code, ID_1 and ID_2. So as you can see (and just focus on the input in A2) there will be two separate IDs in the linked workbook. That sheet, or at least a tiny sample of it, looks like this:

[image]

In the first column we see the code we're looking for (which is what we have in A2 of the first one), each of them with different IDs. So as I'm sure you can tell by now, I'm looking for a formula that will allow me to return those values in ID_1 and ID_2 in the first sheet.

I have been going at this for an hour and I'm stumped, so I would greatly appreciate any help provided!

Comment: Hey wizkids, did any of these answers help? if so, could you accept answer on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

well if the two ID will be consecutive in the second list try this:

```
 =index('workbookname'SheetName!columnrangeofserialnumbers,match(A2,'workbookname'Sheetname!columnrangeofIDs,0))
```

Assuming your other workbook is called Serials, and all the info is on sheet1 you would enter the follow in B2:

```
 =index('serials'sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000,match(A2,'serials'sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000,0))
```

in C2 enter the following (assuming ids will show up consecutively)

```
 =index('serials'sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000,match(A2,'serials'sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000,0)+1)
```

This only works if the other workbook is open as far as I know and with the understanding that the two ID will be listed consecutively in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more generic code if the ids are NOT listed consecutively: Obviously I have done this as an example to take in a more general case where the ids occur anywhere throughout the second dataset, AND where there are potentially several.

```
IFERROR(INDEX($V$2:$V$15, SMALL(IF($U$2:$U$15=$M2, ROW($U$2:$U$15), FALSE), COLUMNS($N2:N2))-ROW($V$1), 1), "")
```

This formula must be entered with **Ctrl-Shift-Enter** before copying across and down! Note all absolute and relative referencing/locking ($ signs)

[image: Page set-up with Array Formula]

The logical steps in constructing such a formula:

1) We use IF function to test if the values in the column U match the value in column M.

2) In the 'value-if-true' parameter, we will get the corresponding row number of values in column U. These numbers will be fed later in the SMALL function.

3) In the value-if-false part, we just return false, as that will later be used as a non-number in the SMALL function

Above 3 steps in the part: `IF($U$2:$U$15=$M2, ROW($U$2:$U$15), FALSE)`

4 ) We have now an array of mixed row numbers and FALSE values, which we want to feed to the INDEX function to simply get the corresponding value in column V(our second datset). BUT as we wish to retrieve the different row matches for each code, we have to fish them out of the mixed array with the SMALL function.

5) using our columns as an incrementer, we apply the SMALL function to the array with a varying ***k*** parameter. We USE the COLUMNS function (note carefully the different $ sign usage), so that as we drag the formula across, the column count increments: `COLUMNS($N2:N2)` - giving K values of 1, 2, 3, 4 as we drag the formula across from column N to column Q. Note that it is useful that the SMALL function disregards FALSE values when looking through the array for the values by size.

[image]

6) There is an adjustment to account for the fact that the rows are relative to the 'Ids' range which we will feed into the INDEX function to retrieve the different ids. `SMALL(IF($U$2:$U$15=$M2, ROW($U$2:$U$15), FALSE), COLUMNS($N2:N2))-ROW($V$1)`.

This can be avoided if we use the entire column V as the look-up array parameter in the INDEX function, but that's another way...

7) This resulting value can now be passed to the INDEX function to obtain the various ids. The column_num parameter of 1 which I put in the function isn't necessary in a single-column look-up array, but is there for completeness.

8) The entire construction is then wrapped in an IFERROR function to give an empty string if there is no match, but some people may wish to have error outputs there...